# Создание массива с внешними ссылками на странице

Tags: javascript, массивы, ссылки

Изучаю js, нужно сделать массив со всеми внешними ссылками на странице.
Нахожу все ссылки на странице с помощью "document.links", а вот отсеять ссылки с этого же домена, и оставить только на внешние сайты не получается. Пытаюсь с помощью регулярных выражений, и что то все не то пытаюсь...

Comment: Тебе же елементы страницы сыпятся, ты должен у них взять атрибут ссылки, затем уже его сравнивать при помощи .indexOf или регл